# Fold or map function & pass in list as parameter Clarity Smart contracts

Tags: stack, smartcontracts, clarity-lang, stacks-blockchain

I have a question regarding the fold or map function and how they can be used. This, as well as passing in a list.

1. how can the fold or map function be used to run another function more then once?
2. How can i pass in a list as a parameter to a function?

Answer (score 0):

1. Fold and map both iterate over defined lists, but work a bit differently, map will apply a specific function to each element of the list separately. Fold will recursively apply the specified function to the previous result. So depending on what exactly your goal is, you can use either of those functions to run a function more than once.
2. You just need to define the name of the parameter and the max number of items and item type when you define the function, like this: `(define-public (use-my-list (newList (list 10 uint)))`.